# How to use a fetched access token to fetch an endpoint?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, fetch-api, access-token

How can I use (insert) a (just) fetched access token in JavaScript to get access to an endpoint (access ID is to be added to the endpoint URI - oauth2 - Strava API).

I tried to add the fetched access token as const and var to the URI of the endpoint, but I do not get any data returned. All is working if I manually insert the actual access_code in the URI (FETCHED_ACCESS_TOKEN), but how do I pick it up to be used automatically in the endpoint URI?

JAVASCRIPT CODE I USED:

```
let _data = {
    client_id:"11111",
    client_secret:"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
    code:"exchange_code",
    grant_type:"authorization_code"
}

fetch("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/oauth/token", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(_data),
  headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
})
.then(response => response.json()) 
.then(json => console.log(json))
.then(json => {data = json})
.then(res => getActivities(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));


const auth_link = "https://www.strava.com/oauth/token"

async function getActivities(res) {

    const activities_link = "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/11111111?access_token=FETCHED_ACCESS_TOKEN"

                await fetch(activities_link)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(json => console.log(json));

            }
```

Comment: From where FETCHED_ACCESS_TOKEN is coming?

Comment: `.then(json => {data = json})` can't work. The previous `.then()` didn't return anything, it just called `console.log()`. And this one doesn't return anything, so the next `.then()` won't work, either.

Comment: What does the JSON returned by the `oauth/token` look like? Is the token in there?

Comment: I do get an access and refresh token returned which I need to use to get the getactivities endpoint ; {token_type: 'Bearer', expires_at: 1681425284, expires_in: 15892, refresh_token: 'dc5ce39b0031665a086a79e94f5c1f7f241bnh11', access_token: '329961b44147c510c58c13694dd4b34c01f44b51', …}

When used like in code Barmar, I get error: access_token is not defined at getActivities

Answer (score 1):

Your cascaded `.then()` calls are not correct, because you're not returning something from each of them. Use a multi-line function instead of multiple `.then()`.

Get the fetched access token from the result of the first API call.

```js
fetch("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/oauth/token", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(_data),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    getActivities(data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));



 async function getActivities(res) {
  const fetched_access_token = res.access_token;
  const activities_link = `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/11111111?access_token=${fetched_access_token}`

  await fetch(activities_link)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
}
```

Comment: I (still) get error: access_token is not defined at getActivities (exchange_

Comment: What does `console.log(res)` show?